# req.user is a list, I have to do req.user[0].prop to get data. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Before I was able to do `req.user.property` to get data, but all of a sudden that failed and I have to do `req.user[0].property` to get data.

Essentially req.user is a list. It looks like this...

```
user: 
[ { _id: '934715373258035',
   active: true,
   date: 'July 1st 2015, 1:44:49 am',
   email: 'username@emailprovider.com',
   genre: '53d8fcd1ea70ad64d6655fa8',
   location: '53d8ff38ea70ad64d6655fbb',
   name: 'First Last',
   pass: 'QAt9tSGDpft7iSxwoa5gsTO63ONXshREQmkE8F6MKqRA6IIn2Eo49Z5vZFqKushX' } ],
```

Why is this and what is causing it? Is this normal? It didn't seem to be in my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to force req.user to be an object (instead of an object within a list) I changed my `passport.deserializeUser` function to run the command `db.users.findOne()` instead of `db.users.find()`.

This returns only the first result and allows req.user to be equal to an object instead of a list that contained the object.

Still not sure what originally caused it to turn in to a list since it should still only return one result...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `req.user.property` has changed from an object literal to an array. In an object literal, you'd be able to access the property by name.

```
var objectLiteral = {name: 'foo'};

objectLiteral.name === 'foo' // true
```

In an array, you have to access the members by index.

```
var arrayOfObjectLiterals = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]

arrayOfObjectLiterals[0].name === 'foo' // true
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, currently you have array of entities (users), so that's why you can't access your properties just be `req.user.propertie`.

In order to access some prop. of array, you need to select specific item for this array and then access needed property.

Possible the issue is related to the fact that previously you were receiving jason object and now it's array of json objects.

Example
Array: `var objects =  [obj1][obj2][obj3];`

To select specific item you need to access it by index: `objects[0] //obj1`

And then you can access properties of 'obj1': `objects[0].someProp`